# Using an HTTP proxy server to stream IPTV sources

Tags: rest, proxy, video-streaming, iptv

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question but I'm hoping to find directions here.

I have a smart tv and I like to watch tv from my country with the SSIPTV app. I found an android app that streams local channels, so I checked the requests with android studio to find the streaming links. Some of them are free, but some others are served through cloudfront. The problem is that I can't add a header needed for cloudfront to authorize the request.

For example: when I try to make a request without the "User-Agent" header, the response is this:

```
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 560
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 01 Jan 2019 20:57:50 GMT
Server: CloudFront
Via: 1.1 f7e7b00c5c66a4e43041ba24c378d07a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: uZQAVTrQzHsQe2vGyHxY1OYfjHCL-Nz7gCTG-koHcgr1A5HG7fGGOg==
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H1>403 ERROR</H1>
        <H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
        <HR noshade size="1px">
Request blocked.


        <BR clear="all">
        <HR noshade size="1px">
        <PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: TZztsUjltHpEhx54wplzupvLmZwjCRPtAvTcbdJ8DL16b1k9-_XwZw==
</PRE>
        <ADDRESS></ADDRESS>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

But if I set the "User-Agent" header with the value "iPhone" this is the response:enter code here

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, User-Agent, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Range
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date, Server, Content-Type, Content-Length
Cache-Control: max-age=1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 366
Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
Date: Tue, 01 Jan 2019 20:51:32 GMT
Server: WowzaStreamingEngine/4.7.6
Via: 1.1 880eb84cefca849ee159a7c4d89c31ea.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: pogc8_OBsN2-QeGj_1q8K_vyxrQH-G8a2JmWqSkVt9x57NlbKfDSdQ==
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
```

So, is there a way I could set up a proxy to add the request and then get the content served in my tv app?

Answer (score 0):

If you can configure your TV app to use an HTTP proxy, then this is straightforward, eg in squid this is documented here: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_header_add/

```
request_header_add User-Agent "iPhone"
```